# Match one ant regex but not other

Tags: java, regex, ant

I want to allow the following syntax for my ant property 
`foo_abc:bar1,bar2,blah|foo_def:bar1,bar2|s64lk:kj,34kj`

I wrote the below ant condition to validate and store in `legalmyprop`. First `matches` matches the full valid string. The following `not matches` explicitly disallow any other special characters that user may try. The `not` matches does not seem to be working

```
<condition property="legalmyprop" value="${myprop}">
  <and>
      <matches string="${myprop}" pattern="^[^:,|]+:[^,:|]+(,[^:,|]+)*(\|[^:,|]+:[^:,|]+(,[^:,|]+)*)*$" />
      <not> <matches string="${myprop}" pattern="^.*[ =}{.;)(]+\*^\\'].*$" /> </not>
      <not> <matches string="${myprop}" pattern='^.*["].*$' /> </not>
  </and>
</condition>
```

`foo:bar,` Fails as expected

`foo_abc:bar1,bar2,blah|foo_def:bar1,bar2|s64lk:kj,34kj` Passes as 
expected

`foo::bar|` Fails as expected

`foo:bar.abc` Passes as unexpected

`foo:bar=abc` Passes as unexpected

Any ideas how to fix the regex?

Comment: Found the issue `]` in the `not matches` has to be changed to `\[`. However I don't understand why this is an issue. So I will leave the question open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at your current not match condition:

```
^.*[ =}{.;)(]+\*^\\'].*$
   ^        ^
   |        |
 Start     End of the character class
```

The current char class is `[ =}{.;)(]` and you wanted it to be:

```
[ =}{.;)(\]+\*^\\']
         ^
```

To work as expected